# Ask Siri to set timer with alarm

Tags: iphone, siri, ios

I do listen stuff before falling asleep and for that I set the native timer on my iPhone to stop playing after ~30 minutes.

When I cook something I ask Siri to set timer for let's say 5 minutes, but after the 5 minutes, my iPhone just stops playing (there is nothing playing at that moment actually).

How do I tell Siri I want to be notified after the timer runs out?

Comment: How can the iPhone '... just stops playing ...' if there's '... nothing playing ... at that moment'?

Comment: I have no idea. Ask Apple, they designed the feature. iOS is not questioning  whether anything is playing. It just lets You setup and start the timer and after time has passed, there is nothing wrong with stop playing nothing.